Anonymize polygons by applying random translation in Earth Engine
I need to make some confidential polygon data partly available to other uses, and would like to anonymize the data. The idea would be to apply a random translation that would preserve the shape of the polygon yet move it at some distance/angle from its original origin. Ideally the distance/angle would be different for each polygon, though it could also be the same for all (and in that case I could set myself the distance/angle).
Are there any functions for that? Any hints on how I should proceed?
var polygon1 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-122.09, 37.42],
   [-122.09, 37.43],
   [-122.08, 37.43],
   [-122.08, 37.42]]
]);

var polygon2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-122.10, 37.41],
   [-122.10, 37.42],
   [-122.09, 37.42],
   [-122.09, 37.41]]
]);

var feature1 = ee.Feature(polygon1, {name: 'Polygon 1'});
var feature2 = ee.Feature(polygon2, {name: 'Polygon 2'});

var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection([feature1, feature2]);


You can try this function, which translates polygons with a random, small offset to anonymize their original location.
/**
 * This function helps anonymize spatial data by applying a random, small translation
 * to each polygon in the input feature collection. The translation preserves the
 * original shape of the polygons while slightly offsetting their position.
 * 
 * Key steps:
 * 1. Adds a random 'offset' column to the feature collection
 * 2. Scales down the random offset to prevent extreme translations
 * 3. Applies the offset to each vertex of the polygon geometries
 */
var translatePolygons = function(fc) {
  // Add a random column for translation offsets
  fc = fc.randomColumn("offset");
  
  // Scale down random offsets to keep translations minimal
  fc = fc.map(function(ft) {
    return ft.set("offset", ee.Number(ft.get("offset")).multiply(0.01));
  });
  
  return fc.map(function(ft) {
    ft = ee.Feature(ft);
    
    var offset = ft.get("offset");
    
    // Extract coordinates of the feature's geometry
    var coords = ft.geometry().coordinates();
    
    // Apply offset to each vertex of the polygon
    var newCoords = coords.map(function(polygons) {
      polygons = ee.List(polygons);
      
      return polygons.map(function(vertexCoords) {
        vertexCoords = ee.List(vertexCoords);
        vertexCoords = vertexCoords.map(function(vertexCoord) {
          return ee.Number(vertexCoord).add(offset);
        });
        
        return vertexCoords;
      });
    });
    
    // Create a new geometry with translated coordinates
    var newGeometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(newCoords);
    return ft.setGeometry(newGeometry);
  });
};

var anonymizedPolygons = translatePolygons(featureCollection);

Map.centerObject(featureCollection);
Map.addLayer(featureCollection, {color:"red"});
Map.addLayer(anonymizedPolygons, {color:"blue"});


thanks Iago! The code will fail though if the geometry is a multiPolygon and not a Polygon. Is there a way to make the code robust to the geometry of the feature?

Rather than mapping over all the individual coordindates (expensive), you can transform each polygon to a new projection.
// Random numbers are between 0 and 1.  Scale them to something visible.
var SCALE = 3

var collection = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Polygon([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]))
])

collection = collection.randomColumn("xoffset").randomColumn("yoffset")

function move(f) {
  var geo = f.geometry()
  // Shift the projection and get the shifted coordinates.
  var proj = geo.projection().translate(
        f.getNumber("xoffset").multiply(SCALE), 
        f.getNumber("yoffset").multiply(SCALE))
  var coords = geo.transform(proj).coordinates()
  // Make a new geometry and remove the evidence.
  return f.setGeometry(ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords)).set({
    xoffset: null,
    yoffset: null
  })
}

Map.addLayer(collection)
Map.addLayer(collection.map(move))


thanks Noel! The code will fail though if the geometry is a multiPolygon and not a Polygon. Is there a way to make the code robust to the geometry of the feature?
